# Почему не работает кнопка и не создаётся диалог?

Tags: jquery, jdialog

Салют!

Не могу понять, почему не работает кнопка и не создаётся диалог.

Синтаксис вроде правильный, хотя в разных источниках вместо фигурных скобок пишут квадратные, но, думаю, это не критично.

Может, кто-то откомментировать код jquery UI? Где ошибка?

[link text](http://jsfiddle.net/Kirg/ucwbgxb9/1/)

Comment: Так это не обычный JQuery, а доп. библиотека jqueryUI

Comment: )) Это было бы вторым вопросом - правильно ли я там все подключаю? Я видел на скринах, что можно UI подключить автоматически, а не вручную через ссылку. Но слева нет выбора UI. Есть только YUI - но это из совсем другой басни.

Answer (score 1):

[[@Körg](/users/24958/k%C3%B6rg)](/users/24958/k%C3%B6rg), песочница - это далеко не идеальный инструмент для разработки. Если у выбранной вами версии jQuery нет дополнительных пуктов по подключению UI, то подключайте сами из [CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide?hl=ru&csw=1#jquery-ui) в "*External Resources*" и [всё будет работать](http://jsfiddle.net/ucwbgxb9/4/). Если же версия не особо важна, то выбирайте jQuery 1.9.1 + jQuery UI 1.9.2. Тогда подключать вручную не придётся.